# Unable to add bulk contacts in AWS SES using cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-ses

I am trying to run a simple command from aws documentation to upload the contacts.csv from S3 bucket to SES, while trying to do so, am constantly getting the error:

**An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the CreateImportJob operation (reached max retries: 15): None**

I have awscli 2.1.38 installed

The command I have used to transfer bulk contacts from an S3 bucket object to SES from documentation is:

````
aws sesv2 create-import-job \                                                                                                                                  
--import-destination "{\"ContactListDestination\": {\"ContactListName\":\"ExampleContactListName\", \"ContactListImportAction\":\"PUT\"}}" \
--import-data-source "{\"S3Url\": \"s3://wwsexampletest/email-test\",\"DataFormat\": \"CSV\"}" --profile sameer```

Let me know, if you can run this command in your account. FYI, my SES is out of Sandbox.
````

Comment: Do you have access to the s3 bucket?

Comment: @Lucasz - I have created the bucket myself in this account only.

Comment: did you end up finding an answer I am getting a similar error: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateImportJob operation: User: arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/pinpoint is not authorized to perform: mobiletargeting:CreateImportJob on resource: arn:aws:mobiletargeting:ap-southeast-2:xxx:apps/string